# Show posts by user

Tags: php, wordpress

So, here is my php to show posts for wordpress:

```
<div class="rfp_hide" id="rhm_profile_item">
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'orderby' => 'date',        
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    global $product, $post, $paged; 
?>
<div class="rhm_post_container">
      Posts go here
</div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>  

</div>
```

It shows all the posts regardless of who posted.

Each post has its href as following:

```
<a class="royal_author_link" href="<?php echo $userpro->permalink( $post->post_author ); ?>">
```

On the post author page, the permalink has following structure :

```
example.com/profile/someone.
```

Now, how can I modify it so that when I am in a specific user page, it only shows the posts by that user only?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use a custom plugin to create the profile page?
In case you have access to the user ID related to the page, you can extend the query argument by the attribute **"author"**, like so:

```
$args = array( 
    'author' => $yourUserID
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'orderby' => 'date',        
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i am trying to avoid using the plugin. Would you happen to know how to generate profile page and show the posts by that specific user? Thanks!

Comment: Could you describe the use case a little bit further? Do you need to create the user pages dynamically on user registration or is it sufficient to create them manually?

Comment: So for example, when an user first registers for the site (let's call the new user name "mike"),  then the user profile page is dynamically generated with a pre-defined  permalink structure (such as 'example.com/profile/mike).  Then when other users visits his page, then they see all the posts created by Mike. I am not sure what needs to be done.

Comment: I would suggest the following: register a custom post type called "user_page" and then insert a post on user creation using the "**user_register**"-action (see [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)). To insert a "user_page" post, you can use the function **wp_insert_post**. To save the corresponding user ID to the post, attach it as meta data using **add_metadata**. Then create a new template for the cpt-type "user_page" and query the posts like in my response ($yourUserID is then received from the metadata).

Comment: But as this relates to a different problem, please open a new question if you need help.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I am going to try with the plugin first to familiarize myself then dive into what you suggested. =) Thank you and I will edit what I have tried regarding the original question.